# PHP Codeigniter 3.1.10: Unable to update session data

Tags: codeigniter

Happen to be stuck since almost a day. Scoured in google searching as to why this isn't working as expected, and also couple of answered questions in stackoverflow, but couldn't figure out as to why it's not working.
Basically i am setting session data during login, like

```
            foreach($response as $item) {
                $sess_array = array(
                    'user_id' => $item->id,
                    'photo' => $item->user_pic,
                );
            }
            // Create session
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
```

And now I am attempting to update a particular variable named 'photo'.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('photo', $new_name);
```

And when I try to display the value of the session variable 'photo' in my view, it still shows the old value and not the updated value.

Below are the entries from config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Codeigniter version 3.1.10
OS Windows 10

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all just check in you autoload.php did you load the session library or not.
or else load session library in your controller. `$this->load->library('session');`

```
foreach($response as $item) { // looping your obj $response
                    $sess_array = array( // set an array 
                        'user_id' => $item->id,
                        'photo' => $item->user_pic,
                    );
                }

print_r($sess_array); you will get the last element of you $response obj here. 
                // Create session
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array); // here you are setting the last obj of $response in you session logged_in

`$this->session->set_userdata('photo', $new_name);` // here you store an variable $new_name in session `photo`
```

redirect from your controller current function to new function after setting the session.
for example.

```
class session extend CI_Controller{
function set_session(){
 $new_name = 'xyz';
 $this->session->set_userdata('photo', $new_name);
 return redirect('session/get_session');
}
function get_session(){
 $this->load->view('sample');
}

}
```

In your view `sample.php`

```
<body><h1>
<?php 
echo $this->session->userdata('photo'); 
// here you got out put 'xyz'
?>
</h1></body>
```

Hope you can find the issue where you go wrong.

Comment: Have already autoloaded the session in autoload.php.
Regarding the redirection, thats pretty much the same how i have implemented, i.e. update session variable and redirect('upload_success'). But when i print the value of session variable, it still shows up old value.

Comment: May be it is because of the older version of codeigniter. try to unset user data and set it again. may that will be helpful. i think it does update userdate when we set with same name. and print the $_SESSION variable in your view. to see if any thing went wrong.

Comment: Tried unsetting it and setting it again, but no luck. Strange that there are several suggestions stating that it will work, but not working for me. Not sure what i am missing.